# Trying to override _beforeSave method and Magento calling both custom method and core method as well

Tags: magento

All I am trying to override the **_beforeSave()** method in resource model **Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer**.

There is no problem in overriding as I can get the call to my **custom _beforeSave** method in my Custom Class.

Config for my custom Class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<config>
    <modules>
        <Abc_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Abc_Customer>
    </modules>

    <global>       
        <models>
            <cust>
                <class>Abc_Customer_Model</class>   
                <resourceModel>cust_resource</resourceModel> 
            </cust>  
            <cust_resource>
                <class>Abc_Customer_Model_Resource</class>
            </cust_resource>
            <customer_resource>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>Abc_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>                
            </customer_resource>    
        </models>
    </global>

</config>
```

After that I have created the **Abc_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer** class, copied the **_beforeSave** method from the core class and changed according to need.

But the problem is now that magento is calling both of the methods.

How can I stop this behaviour and just let only my custom method to run?

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show me _beforeSave method please?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the customer_before_save event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same question was answered [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/6533/146). The main idea is that if you copied the method from the original class, this line `parent::_beforeSave($customer)` will call the original method.
You can replace that line with

```
Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract::_beforeSave($customer);
```

---

thanks @ProxiBlue for the idea.